# BFS: Is there any way to get "eccentricity"?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

`Eccentricity` is the maximum among shortest collaboration distances.

Graph consists of `Adjacent List`.

This is how I implemented in `Java`:

```
  public int eccentricity(String start) {
    Queue<String> queue = new ArrayDeque<String>();
    queue.add(start);

    HashMap<String, Boolean> visitedChecker = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
    visitedChecker.put(start, true);

    // Init distanceHistory
    HashMap<String, Integer> distanceHistory = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    distanceHistory.put(start, 0);

    int eccen = 0;

    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
      String vertex = queue.poll();

      HashSet<String> neighbors = Graph.get(vertex);
      for (String neighbor: neighbors) {
        if (visitedChecker.get(neighbor) == null) {
          visitedChecker.put(neighbor, true);
          eccen = distanceHistory.get(vertex) + 1;
          distanceHistory.put(neighbor, eccen);
          queue.add(neighbor);
        }
      }
    }
    return eccen;
  }
```

But problem of this code is slow!... (about 3 times slower than fastest one)

But I THINK that there is nothing to do to make my code faster...

And I think `Adjcent matrix` would not make it faster...

Any idea? Did I miss something?

Comment: I'm pretty sure using integer vertex identifiers instead of copying `std::string`s around, and storing them in a `vector` or plain array instead of a hashtable, would give you a decent constant-factor speedup.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I agree but unfortunately, identifier is `string type`.. fixed(cannot change)! ..

Comment: Map the strings to small consecutive integers starting at 0, find the eccentricity using them, and then convert the integers back.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I think that that would need a hashing too when finding which integer are matched with a string... then would it be same?

Comment: It doesn't (you could just use whatever natural order the strings were given in, or if they somehow weren't given in any order you could first sort them alphabetically), but even if it did it would still be a net win for large problem instances, since you will only do O(n) string->int or int->string operations, 2 for each vertex (once at the start and once at the end), while currently you do O(n^2) string operations, since you perform lookups inside your inner loop.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thanks for answer but I'm kinda programming novice and non-native english so have some trouble in understanding what you said. If not bother you, could you give me some short example, please? as an answer?

Comment: I think this is a programming competition question, so I don't want to give you actual working code. But the changes needed from your current code to the code I'm thinking of aren't big: basically, you just need to convert the strings to numbers at the start, then do what you are already doing (the main part of the algorithm) except using numbers instead of strings, then afterwards convert them back.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I've already done! Thank you so much! I learned a lot from u